# _xnForceShutdown openni symbol not found

Tags: openni

I had been trying to get OpenNI work on my Mac OS X 10.7. I installed the latest unstable binaries of OpenNI, NITE and Sensor from openni.org. The (precompiled) sample examples from OpenNI work fine but as soon as I write something of my own, it starts to fail.
For example, see below:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_xnForceShutdown", referenced from:
      xn::Context::SetHandle(XnContext*)    in sample.o
  "_xnContextUnregisterFromShutdown", referenced from:
      xn::Context::SetHandle(XnContext*)    in sample.o
  "_xnContextRelease", referenced from:
      xn::Context::SetHandle(XnContext*)    in sample.o
  "_xnContextAddRef", referenced from:
      xn::Context::SetHandle(XnContext*)    in sample.o
  "_xnContextRegisterForShutdown", referenced from:
      xn::Context::SetHandle(XnContext*)    in sample.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [AsusCamera] Error 1

My code is as follows:

```
    #include "XnOpenNI.h" 
    #include "XnCppWrapper.h" 

    using namespace xn; 
    extern "C" int printf(const char *, ...); 

    int main() {
            Context context; 
            printf("hello world\n"); 
            context.Release(); 
            return 1; 
    };
```

Please help me. I already tried re-installing the libs several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just compiled your code on OSX (albeit 10.6.8) using Qt Creator and Xcode and it works.
The `undefined symbols` usually means you haven't linked to the library(dylib) the header files reference, so link libOpenNI.dylib to your project.

In Qt Creator I have this setup:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = niTest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/ni/
LIBS += /usr/lib/libOpenNI.dylib
```

In XCode I've dragged libOpenNI.dylib onto the project and ticked the "Copy items into desintation group's folder (if needed)", had `/usr/include/ni/` path added to the header search path. Note that depending on what feature you end up using in OpenNI/NITE, you will need to link to other libraries as well (e.g. libnimCodecs,libXnCore,etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I had to use just the lib path lib name (e.g. OpenNI, XnCore). Eclipse does the rest (lib + * + .dylib). After applying your changes I could compile but still could not run the program. It complained about missing binary. I messed up my gcc settings hoping to fix this and now I am re-installing xcode and hoping that gcc/g++ will be re-installed and I can start working on the actual problem!